# Configuring existing hyperledger nodes with hyperledger cello

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-cello

I have deployed [two org hyperledger fabric network[1](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/tutorials/deploy-to-fabric-multi-org). Now I want to integrate it with hyperledger Cello. I have installed it, now I am bit confused what values shall I put in **Add host** fields as per my installed network(please refer to link regarding peer ip and port). Its just a simple network on my local machine with docker(not swarm or kubernetes).

Answer (score 0):

Cello is used to deploy fabric network you can find the container configuration file in [fabric.solo.yaml](https://github.com/hyperledger/cello/tree/master/src/agent/docker/_compose_files/fabric-1.0)

once you add your host go to chain tab and add new chain network

write on your terminal  `docker ps`  you will find the container created